# Links in Chrome Apps

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, google-chrome-app

I am making a Chrome App and I have a clickable hyperlink that I want to display a webpage, but I don't want to use `_blank` for example which takes me to my web browser, I want to stay inside the app if that makes sense.

Unfortunately "Apps don't have a built-in concept of in-window navigation, so such links are prohibited". On the internet it said I can "add an on click handler to the link and do something fancier". But I don't know how to do that.

I have tried using an `<iframe>` but you cant link a https website in an iframe.   Here's what I've tried:

```
<a href="https://login.bookatable.com/login" target="_blank"> CLICK ME </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You *really* can't navigate, i.e. substitute your app's page with another page, be it another page in your app or an external page.

To display external web content in an app, you need to embed a [`<webview>` element](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview), which behaves similarly to an iframe.

You need to attach a listener to your "link" UI element that would make the webview appear with the correct `src`.